# Gridview highlight a row when clicked using jquery when there are multiple tables on a page

Tags: jquery, gridview, onclick, row, highlight

my code is like this

```
    <table>
      <tr><td> report heading </td> </tr>
      <tr><td>export to excel button</td></tr>
      <tr><td> 
         <table id=tblGridview>
          <tr><td><asp:gridview cssclass = "OFGrid" id="grdviewID"></asp:gridview></td></tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

and am using below jquery to highlight the row when clicked
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').filter(function() {
            return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
        }).click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('currRow');
        });
    });
```

this works fine, but the problem is this gets trigerred for all the tr.  Even when i click the first two rows which has "report heading" and "Export to excel" button, that row gets highlighted.  how do i change the jquery to such a way that the jquery gets triggered only when any row from gridview is clicked.  since gridview itself is getting emitted as table, how do i limit the jquery specific to that table.

and if possible it will beof great help if someone explains how this jquery works line by line.  i just simply don't understand it.

kindly help.  Thanks.

Comment: also the above code is giving javascript error after page is posted back.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the first 2 rows inside your `filter()` condition:

```
return this.index() > 1 && $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length;
```

Comment: below code is giving object dosen't support this property or method.   <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('tr').filter(function() {
            return this.index() > 1 && $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length;
            }).click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('currRow');
            });
        });
        
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gt(index)` selector which filters element collection to only elements with index greater than index provided in selector

```
$('table').find('tr:gt(1)')....
```

If this causes problems in nested tables, you should likely look at adding some classes to either tables or rows

```
$('table.allowClickClass tr')....
```

OR

```
$('tr').not('.noClickClass')....
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

**EDIT** ANother simple selector that might work if I understand issue would be:

```
/* only apply handler to nested tables*/
$('tr table tr').click...
```

Comment: $('table').find('tr:gt(1)').  does it get triggered when i click on any tr.  note that i have more than one table in my page.  i can identify the gridview using the class .OFGrid.  does that help?  can you provide me the full code that i shd be having.

Comment: not totally clear **exactly** what behavior you want... all rows in Gridview?? Only Gridview? etc

Comment: post some live html in jsfiddle.net

Comment: i want the click functionality for all rows of gridview but not for rows outside of gridview like the heading row of table and "Export to excel" row

Comment: @charlieftfl am not sure which line i hv to replace your code.  totally new to Jquery.  can you give me the full function?

Comment: show me some live html for section `<asp:gridview>`  I do no asp work at all...assume it is just a table but not sure

Comment: @charlieftfl  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width = "100%" align ="center" >
        <tr align ="center">
            <td>
                <strong>Raw detail report</strong></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divrpt" class="divrpt">
                    <asp:GridView ID="Grdrpt" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CssClass="OFGrid">
<Columns></Columns></asp:GridView></div></td></tr>

Comment: i tried this in jfiddle.net.  'tr table tr' is working in jfiddle.  but the same is not working in my web page.  the HTML that i pasted above is a child page.  is that causing a issue?

Comment: copy browser source code of a live page to fiddle and save it.. will get it working with real full html. Help to have a full table and sub grid

Comment: finally below code worked(is there anyway to optimize it?), but the same code does not work after postback of page.(i have export to excel button on same page, when i click it, it postbacks and the same page is loaded once again. am able to see the grid).not sure why. $(document).ready(function() {
            $('tr').filter(function() {
            if ($(this).parent().parent().attr("id") == "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GrdViewId") {
                    return $(this);
                }
            }).click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('currRow');
            });
        });